# Extracting a jar library during runtime

Tags: java, jar

I have created a class called `JarUnpacker` that I want to use at the first of my main program in order to unpack the `.jar` library added by another developer.
But it extract an un-useful file. Can some one help me what should I do?
Here's my code:

```
public class JarUnpacker {

  public void setFile(InputStream io, String fileName) throws IOException {
    new File("lib").mkdir();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
    byte[] buf = new byte[256];
    int read = 0;
    while ((read = io.read(buf)) > 0) {
      fos.write(buf, 0, read);
    }
  }

  public void unpack() {
    InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("lib/TobeUnpacked.jar");
    try {
      this.setFile(input,"lib/TobeUnpacked");
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
      System.out.println("failed");
      e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    JarUnpacker j = new JarUnpacker();
    j.unpack();
  } 

}
```

Comment: make sure *lib/TobeUnpacked.jar* is available where you end up looking for it.

Comment: it is available. it's exactly in lib folder

Comment: Add the line `System.out.println(getClass().getResource("lib/TobeUnpacked.jar"));` just before the line where you get the input stream. It will tell you where exactly the jar is expected.

Comment: not sure what you want to achieve - your `setFile` method just copies the jar file (and it does so successfully if the file is found)